# scrollview doesnt scroll only if put more elements

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

Why this scrollview doesnt work? I have two textview on layout and doesnt work until i put another textview. It's seems scrollview map size for elements and not content size.

Here my layout(xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
                    android:id="@+id/mainactivity_maintab_aria_bubble"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_mainactivity_about"
                    android:background="@drawable/mainactivitiy_bubble_aria_background"
                    android:textColor="#EBEBEB"
                    style="@style/flat_chat_bubble"/>

                <TextView
                    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
                    android:id="@+id/mainactivity_maintab_user_bubble"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_mainactivity_rate"
                    android:background="@drawable/mainactivitiy_bubble_user_background"
                    android:textColor="#EBEBEB"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/mainactivity_maintab_aria_bubble"
                    style="@style/flat_chat_bubble"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is your layout's content bigger than the screen?? I suppose not.

Comment: Yes, i tested on multiple devices!

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <ScrollView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">



               <RelativeLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                      <TextView
                         android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit     amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
                         android:id="@+id/mainactivity_maintab_aria_bubble"
                         android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_mainactivity_about"
                         android:textColor="#EBEBEB"
                         style="@style/flat_chat_bubble"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum  dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
                                android:id="@+id/mainactivity_maintab_user_bubble"
                                android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_mainactivity_rate"
                             android:background="@drawable/mainactivitiy_bubble_user_background"
                               android:textColor="#EBEBEB"
                             android:layout_below="@+id/mainactivity_maintab_aria_bubble"
                               style="@style/flat_chat_bubble"/>
             </RelativeLayout>

       </ScrollView>
```

Comment: cant use layout_below with linearlayout. if i use linearlayout the second textview goes to right side of first. The scroll works.